# Is it possible to put in If statement what should be the conditon?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$roll1 = rand(1,6);
$roll2 = rand(1,6);
$roll3 = rand(1,6);
$roll4 = rand(1,6);
?>
```

How can add this in
if (any two variable == 6)
{
Condition
}

Comment: If you weren't doing that noobish thing of "numbering variable names", but used an _array_ instead - then you could simply use `array_count_values` to determine this real quickly.

Comment: Have your rolls in an array instead of separate variables. Then use `array_intersect` against  `[6,6]`. Or what @CBroe said, then `$counted[6] === 2` is all you need.

Comment: Did yhe answer work for you

Answer (score 1):

Here's the complete version

```php
 $rolls = [];

 // Fill the array
 for ($i=1; $i<=4; $i++)
 {$rolls [$i] = rand(1,6);}

// Get an array of counts
 $counts = array_count_values($rolls);

//How many sixes are there, if null returns 0
 $sixes = $counts[6] ?? 0;

// Check if exactly 2 sixes exist
 $exactly_two = $sixes === 2;

//Show Rolls and Counts
print_r ($rolls);
echo "<br>";
print_r ($counts);
```